# Integrating ReactiveCocoa using carthage fails

Tags: ios, swift, reactive-cocoa, carthage

I am trying to create a fresh iOS/Swift project and integrating [ReactiveCocoa](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa) using [carthage](https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage).

I am running Xcode 7.1.1.

My *cartfile* just has one line:

```
github "ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa"
```

When running `carthage update`, I am getting the following build errors:

The following build commands failed:

`CompileSwift normal x86_64 Users/nburk/Developer/RxTicTacToe/Carthage/Checkouts/Result/Carthage/Checkouts/Box/Box/Box.swift`

`CompileSwift normal x86_64 /Users/nburk/Developer/RxTicTacToe/Carthage/Checkouts/Result/Carthage/Checkouts/Box/Box/MutableBox.swift`

`CompileSwiftSources normal x86_64 com.apple.xcode.tools.swift.compiler`

(3 failures)

Then some more info:

/Users/nburk/Developer/RxTicTacToe/Carthage/Checkouts/Result/Carthage/Checkouts/Box/Box/Box.swift:6:37: error: 'Printable' has been renamed to 'CustomStringConvertible'

/Users/nburk/Developer/RxTicTacToe/Carthage/Checkouts/Result/Carthage/Checkouts/Box/Box/Box.swift:31:10: error: 'toString' has been renamed to 'String'

/Users/nburk/Developer/RxTicTacToe/Carthage/Checkouts/Result/Carthage/Checkouts/Box/Box/MutableBox.swift:8:51: error: 'Printable' has been renamed to 'CustomStringConvertible'

/Users/nburk/Developer/RxTicTacToe/Carthage/Checkouts/Result/Carthage/Checkouts/Box/Box/MutableBox.swift:25:10: error: 'toString' has been renamed to 'String'
A shell task failed with exit code 65:
** BUILD FAILED **

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's still no stable release of `ReactiveCocoa 4`, and since you're not specifying a version, it's downloading the last stable one: `3.0`, which isn't compatible with `Swift 2.x`.

What you want to do is add a specific version:.

```
github "ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa" "v4.0.0-RC.2"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try 
`github "ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa" ~> 4.0` in Cartfile